# find out physically connected cisco switches

Tags: switching

I am working with hardware guys and trying to monitor switches.Those guys deployed switches with some connectors,to implement such a logic in which whenever switch A goes down switch B goes down as well, very similar to a tree structure or parent/child.I can login to switch interfaces,problem is how I can find this connection between two switches.The idea is network monitoring needs to implement same tree logic between them.I am an alien to network hardware.

Comment: show cdp neighbors

Comment: You are also trying to re-invent the wheel.  There are many, many products, freeware, and methods for monitoring equipment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending in the exact makes and models, very often some kind of discovery protocol is used.

E.g. for Cisco switches `show cdp neighbors`

For HPE Procurve/Aruba switches `show lldp info remote`

(Note that CDP [proprietary Cisco] and LLDP [open IEEE] are distinct protocols. On most devices, CDP shows no LLDP devices and vice versa. HPE/Aruba often bunches them all together though.)

For more detailed information you'll need to add the device info to your question. Note that discovery protocols are L2-only, so the switches need to be connected directly or via L2-transparent hardware (e.g. media converters) for them to work.

LLDP and CDP are very similar. Both usually show a neighbor's (management) IP or (base) MAC address, device name, features, ... The available information is generally device-specific and varies considerably. The protocols are very common for switches but much less so for other devices.

Once you've got the neighbor information you should update your documentation and configure port/friendly interface names.

If you already know the MAC addresses of the relevant devices you can also use `show mac address-table` to find out which port (and possibly VLAN) they are attached to.

Comment: I have cisco product brand model image version information, I do not know about that hardware which connects two cisco switches, if I had that information I think I could better define the problem as you said.I can not  even walk to switches, due to geo reasons. thnx

Comment: The may be additional hardware between two switches, but very often they are connected directly. Most switches are configured for remote access, e.g. using SSH.

Comment: I was told that those guys used separate apparatus, not like using cable from one to another switch and I do not have that apparatus information, kind of connector I guess.

Comment: There's a vast range of possibilities, so unless you can provide more detailed information we'll likely not be able to help you much further, sorry.

Comment: I can see neighbors with that cdp command, does cisco show similar information if there is a connector-like device attached between two switched?

Comment: That depends on the device. It can add its own CDP frames to the traffic (then you see two devices on a single port) or filter CDP (then you can't discover anything behind). Again, we'd need some more information.

Comment: Lets say switchX switchY switchZ from left to right in a tree structure, when I run "show cdp neighbors detail" command on switchY, I can see two device IDs that belong to switchX with outgoing port and management address information.If I log into switch X and verify management address is the one I see on switchY can I say these two linked with connector-like apparatus? Or either with cable or connector-like apparatus two cisco switches are linked in parent/child manner, regardless of physical connection type, what I need to confirm is they are connected as parent-child.

Comment: Is there such a "device manager" menu like on windows desktop I can see all attached hardware on cisco CLI ?

Comment: *can I say these two linked with connector-like apparatus* - You can only say that they are linked *somehow*. There could be a media converter, a dumb switch, just a cable or many other things in between. As to the "parent/child" thing, you'd need to ask your hardware guys what they have set up.

Comment: That "device manager" you are asking about doesn't exist. Or rather, it's the list of MAC addresses attached to each port (`show mac address-table`) - doesn't tell you much, only which port leads to each device.

Comment: so switchY shows anything connecting switchX to it but physical mediums, not logical?

Comment: A managed switch shows *interface states* - where something is attached by physical layer - and *MAC addresses by port* - what is attached where by data link layer. When available, CDP or LLDP are just a bonus info. They're rather common with switches but not so with other devices.

Comment: "show lldp info remote' command on hp aruba switch gives IP address,connected port,sys name/descr info, this is what I needed to know, if connected device is hp aruba again.But if connected device is cisco switch, it shows chassisid,sys name/descr info and some other IP, I think this IP is nat'ed? how can I find the IP of connected cisco switch which NMS is listing? Interesting to see hp aruba shows more than cisco show for neighboring device.

Comment: hp aruba lldp shows access point info, forgot to tell.

Comment: The info displayed by CDP or LLDP is device-specific. Some devices show their (management) IP, some their (base) MAC, ...

Comment: "show cdp neighbors detail" I can see PORT ID (outgoing port) but I can not see this port when I run "show mac address-table", hoping to see VLAN,ports matching to PORT ID in neighbors.

Comment: hp aruba and cisco switch are connected; "show cdp neighbors" shows nothing on cisco but "show lldp info remote-devices" shows IP,version,port etc on hp aruba which belongs to cisco switch

Comment: `show cdp neighbors` on Cisco shows only devices sending CDP frames (Cisco and a few others). IEEE LLDP is a potentially more widely used protocol.